# start a service before than another

Tags: centos, fedora, services, sysvinit

I want to change the iptables at 3rd.
By default, in directory /etc/rc3.d iptables service is S08iptables and I want to change it to S03iptables

I executed the command below:

```
ckconfig --level 3 iptables on
```

After this I go back to /etc/rc3.d to check if the changes was applied to the file but not.

Am I executing the correct command?

I'd like to know how to make the same thing with systemd because I have a Cent0s7 machine and I looked in /etc/systed/system but the services doesn't show me order

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/812584/in-systemd-whats-the-difference-between-after-and-requires

Answer (score 1):

Systemd doesn’t have hard coded numerical linear ordering like sysv init had. It uses a variety of keywords in the unit file to describe what is started before, after or as part of another service. (See this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/812584/in-systemd-whats-the-difference-between-after-and-requires) for more details, as mentioned in the comments)

So, if you want iptables to run before another service, you can either update the iptables service unit file (systemctl edit iptables.service) and add Before=otherservice.service, or you can edit the otherservice.service file to put After=iptables.service.

Units in systemd aren’t executed sequentially either, so unless you specify some sort of order, they’ll launch simultaneously.

After the system boots, you can use “systemd-analyse critical-chain” to get a better idea of the order in which things started.